# Unity3d Game Tutorial Scavengers 2D My character only moves once

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm new at creating games and I'm programming in C#, and I'm in need of help because I've spent a lot of time trying to make the Unity3d tutorial game the 2D Scavengers, and my character only moves only once and for the rest is normal. Unity does not charge any error in this regard. Could someone help me?

I tried to compare my code with that of the video lessons several times but I did not find any difference.

```
private void Update()
{
    //Só vamos fazer alguma coisa se for o turno do player
    if(!GameManager.instance.playerTurn)return;

    int horizontal = 0;
    int vertical = 0;

    horizontal = (int) (Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"));

    vertical = (int) (Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical"));

    if(horizontal != 0)
    {   
        vertical = 0;
    }

    if(horizontal != 0 || vertical != 0)
    {
        AttemptMove<Wall> (horizontal, vertical);
    }
}
```

Comment: Kinda hard to help out, with this can you tell us what `GameManager.instance.playerTurn` is when it doesnt work? or  show us how that value changes?

Comment: Have you written the code for `GameManager` yet (part 3-06 in the tutorial)?

Comment: Add a link to the tutorial you are following